# I feel ashmaed about this question, what am I?

Tags: riddle

> I was desgined to help, but
>   I can frutsrate some of you
>   I was cretaed by you, so
>   I am impefrect naturally
>   I ate dictoinary full, so
>   I spit wodrs as I see fit
>   I am famliiar to more, than
>   I did mangae in last millennium
>   I sit produly above blocks, and
>   I get smakced like them

What am I

Comment: First question here. Thanks @lois6b for the editing help :)

Comment: this does not seem to be a classic riddle for me, maybe it needs some other tags?

Comment: @elias I thought about adding computer-puzzle tag, but decided against it as it will make the puzzle too easy. Well, now I know it was too easy anyway.

Comment: "I can comlpete you, and I can corerct you, I am cetrain as ever, that I do betetr than this OP"  - Hints, if anyone needs it in full :)

Comment: I was just about to correct the spelling errors in the title and question too...

Comment: I didn't notice anything and just assumed "mangae" is plural of "manga"...

Comment: The first two lines especially bring Clippy to mind.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! A nice idea - would have been great if the misspelled words were all other, correctly spelled words!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution:

> You are the autocorrect

I was desgined to help, but

> Human created it

I can frutsrate some of you

> Some are complicated and not intuitive

I was cretaed by you, so I am impefrect naturally

> Also by human creation

I ate dictoinary full, so
I spit wodrs as I see fit
I am famliiar to more, than
I did mangae in last millennium

> Contains complete dictionaries

I sit produly above blocks, and
I get smakced like them

> the autocorrect is above the keyboard and usually blocks. You tap on them

Comment: :P So it was very easy. May be I need to try harder next time. I will accept once the system allows me to do so.

Comment: dont worry. my first riddle here was simple too, answered by seconds almost hahah but well accepted. +1 see you in next puzzles

Comment: btw, which clue was the give away? The spelling mistakes in the question, or the dictionary line?

Comment: definitely the typos. too many to be casual. the "dictionary" and "spit" were key also